# WebApi differentiating Routing with Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Apologies in advance if this was asked before but I can't find a direct answer that will help me fully understand routing.

Let's say we have the following scenario:

```
1. api/users             Routes to Get() //Retrieves all users
2. api/users/{user}      Routes to Get(string user) //api/users/IE1
3. api/users/?user=IE1   ????????? Get(string user = null, string emailAddress=null...)
```

I am trying to have both 2 and 3 running simultaneously.
The reason I am trying to do this is because 3 can have multiple query parameters such as country, email addresses etc of a user.

Now 2 and 3 will clash with a "Multiple actions were found that match the request" when there is only 1 parameter.

Is there a way to fix this without creating another Route such as /api/users/searchbyUser/ as I am trying to keep it tidy on one Route - users?

Comment: Does route 3 _always_ return exactly one user object or does it return an array of objects?

Comment: it can be one it can also be an array of objects. Basically you are querying all "Users". Is this not common when running parameters to query all? Lets say you want to find all users that are from the UK. It can be more than one

Comment: Ah, so route 3 is essentially route 1 where you filter the results on the server side. Couldn't you move the query parameters to route 1?

Comment: You could yes but wouldn't that be messy? Imagine if there are 50 parameters under "Users" that you want to query. I am trying to see if its possible to keep the two separate

Comment: User (id) and emailAddress _should_ be unique to a user. What's the intention for route 3, to be another lookup (using only unique fields) or a search (there are parameters like "First Name")?

Comment: to be used as a search.

Answer (score 2):

Actually 1 and 3 will clash, not 2 and 3 since you have only nullable parameters on the 3rd get. The Get (1) without any parameters will be the same as (3) all the nullables - there is no difference in signature.

You have multiple options to consider, but I would advise to have only one Get method:
You have one method (no 3) when user = null and no other parameters have values you will return all users (1).
If any of the parameters have values you can return the users based on the query values (like a combination of 2 and 3 if you like).